# Inject Container in Entity Repository

Tags: symfony

I want to get Current locale in my Repository.That's why I am injecting the Container into my Repository but I am getting error that I am unable to figure it out.
This is my `service.yml` code

```
survey.repository.container_aware:
    class: Demo\SurveyBundle\Repository\SurveyRepository
    calls:
        - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```

and this is my repository class code

```
.......

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

.......

protected $container;

public function __construct(Container $container) {
     $this->container = $container;
}
```

After that I am getting below error

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
Demo\SurveyBundle\Entity\SurveyRepository::__construct() must implement 
interface Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, instance of
Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given
```

What I am missing in my construct or in service?

Comment: Why you're trying to inject the whole container? Be more precise and try to inject only the services you depend on, directly.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the container with the `Setter Injection` (in the yml) but you define it in the constructor class.

BTW the entity manager already have a constructor class with arguments so don't take the `Constructor Injection` and simply change your method in the class as:

```
public function setContainer(Container $container) {
     $this->container = $container;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You actually have another major issue here.  From the error message it's obvious that you are trying to access your doctrine repository using the entity manager.  Something like:

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('whatever');
```

The service container code is never being used and it really does not matter what you do, you still won't get your container injected.  Creating a repository as a service requires using the entity manager as a factory and takes some additional lines in your services.yml file.

Something like:

```
# services.yml
cerad_person.person_repository.doctrine:
    class:  Cerad\Bundle\PersonBundle\Entity\PersonRepository
    factory_service: 'doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
    factory_method:  'getRepository'
    arguments:  
        - 'Cerad\Bundle\PersonBundle\Entity\Person'
    calls:
        - [ setContainer, [@container] ] 

// controller
$personRepo = $this->get('cerad_person.person_repository.doctrine');
```

That will give you a repository with the container injected.

@devilciuos - %locale% will only give you the default locale and not whatever is passed as _locale in the request.  Unfortunately it seems to take a listener to access the request local via a service: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5486

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing the container to the constructor, but to `setContainer`. So you shouuld declare a public method `setContainer` in *SurveyRepository*:

*Demo/SurveyBundle/Entity/SurveyRepository.php*

```
protected $container;

public function setContainer(Container $container) {
     $this->container = $container;
}
```

or pass the container to the constructor:

*DemoSurveyBundle/Resources/Config/services.yml*

```
survey.repository.container_aware:
    class: Demo\SurveyBundle\Repository\SurveyRepository
    arguments: [@service_container]
```

Edit:
By the way, if you only need the locale, wouldn't be enough to pass the %locale% parameter instead of the whole container?

```
survey.repository.container_aware:
    class: Demo\SurveyBundle\Repository\SurveyRepository
    calls:
        - [ setLocale, [ %locale%] ]

protected $locale;

public function setLocale($locale) {
     $this->locale = $locale;
}
```

Comment: if the Repository class extends the `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` that already have a constructor i think this doesn't works well..

Comment: So take the first option, then. Declare setContainer in your repository class.

Comment: By the way, @Matteo, wouldnt' be enough to pass just %locale% to the repository?